# Permutations and combinations - divisibility of a factorial

Tags: permutations, factorial

**Question:**

> Find the largest value of $n$ for which $125!$ is divisible by $6^n$

Approach:
I tried to find all the numbers which were a multiple of 6. The number of times such divisors occurred should simply be the value of $n$. However, this proved to be a difficult task. Any simpler approach?

Comment: It is sufficient to find the highest power of $3$ dividing $125!$, which is $3^{59}$

Comment: @Peter How did you come up with that though?

Comment: @Gummybears: Recall [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087629/number-of-zeroes-at-end-of-factorial) of yours from yesterday.

Comment: @hardmath I can use the same method for any number?

Comment: Just as the limiting "factor" for factors of ten is counting the fives in the factorial, here the factors of three are not so many as the factors of two.  So count the scarcer prime factor, using the same "floor" fractions.

Comment: So I cannot use 6, as rogerl has done? @hardmath

Comment: @hardmath So it is only applicable for prime numbers. And that too, we have to use the larger prime factor?

Comment: Gummybears: You should confirm your new understanding by counting the factors of 3 that @Peter claims above.  The computation is rather easily organized using a calculator (applet or hand-held).