# How many is different powers of 10, which divide 1000!? Powers are supposed to be positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many is different powers of 10, which divide 1000! ? Powers are supposed to be positive integers

Comment: $50!$ or $1000!$?

Comment: See also [number of zeroes at the end of factorial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087629/number-of-zeroes-at-end-of-factorial).

Comment: oh, my bad. 1000! of course

Comment: So why did you write 50! in the title?

Comment: @Scientifica Please don't make relatively trivial edits directly in the Low Quality and Close queues, as it will unilaterally complete the review. From the description: "Edit if you can fix _all_ the problems with this [post]".

Comment: @epimorphic Yes you're right. If ever I want to edit without fixing all the problems, I should skip or recommend close the question before editing it. Most of the time I forget after editing I can't flag the question anymore (especially if it's for using LaTeX). I apologize and thank you for your important comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901), it is shown that the number of factors of the prime $p$ in $n!$ is
$$
\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}
$$
where $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits in the base-$p$ representation of $n$.

Since $1000=13000_{\text{five}}$, the number of factors of $5$ in $1000!$ is
$$
\frac{1000-4}{5-1}=249
$$
Since $1000=1111101000_{\text{two}}$, the number of factors of $2$ in $1000!$ is
$$
\frac{1000-6}{2-1}=994
$$
Thus, $10^{249}\mid1000!$ Therefore, the positive powers of $10$ that divide $1000!$ are
$$
10^1, 10^2,10^3,\dots,10^{249}
$$

Comment: The formula is called [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula).